# RequireJS module dependencies and includes

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In my RequestJS config file, I am loading `select2` and I'd like to also load locales for it. I currently have this setup :

```
require.config({
  enforceDefine: true,
  baseUrl: '/js',
  shim: {
    'bootstrap@3.1.1': {
      deps: [ 'jquery' ],
      exports: '$'        // export jQuery...
    },
    'jquery@2.1.1': {
      exports: '$'
    },
    'select2': {
      deps: [ 
        'bootstrap',
        'lib/select2_locales/select2_locale_fr',
        /// NOTE : add locales here
        'css!/css/select2/select2.css',
        'css!/css/select2/select2-bootstrap.css',
      ],
      exports: '$.fn.select2'
    }
  },
  paths: {
    'bootstrap@3.1.1': 'lib/bootstrap.min',
    'jquery@2.1.1': 'lib/jquery.min'
  },
  map: {
    '*': {
      'css': 'css@0.1.2',
      'jquery': 'jquery@2.1.1',
      'bootstrap': 'bootstrap@3.1.1'
    }
  }
});
```

The problem, here, is that `lib/select2_locales/select2_locale_fr` needs to be loaded *after* `select2.min.js`.

Is there some way I can change this configuration, or add an option, so I can load the locales along with `select2`, *from* the require config file?

Answer (score 1):

If that is the case, then select2_locale_fr is not a dependency of select 2, select2 is a dependency of select2_locale_fr

```
define('locale_specific_select2',['select2'], function(select2){
  select2.accomodateNewLocale= function(stuff){
    doWhatYouNeedToWith(stuff);
  }
  locale = determineLocale()
  function processLocaleData(localeData){
    select2.accomodateNewLocale(localeData);
  }
  require(['pathTOLocalePlugin'+locale], processLocaleData);
}
```

Comment: right, but if I need to include more locales, then what? Do I need to create some phony module that is dependant of each locale, which are in return dependant of `select2` ? Seems weird to me.

Comment: You ar etalking about a deifferent module for each locale, a module that has different behaviors and expectation (even thoush those differences are minimal)

Comment: A better approach than the one you are taking would be to load the select2 module, and then determine your locale at runtime before requiring it

Comment: the problem here is how to load the locales *after* `select2` is loaded? Is it "legal" to use requirejs inside the `init` function of the `shim` rule? O_o I don't want to ensure locale loading every time I require `select2`. Unless I wrap `select2` inside a totally custom local module... ?

Comment: I don't know why you are so committed to using the shim for a fairly custom behavior, consider the example I posted above